# vuetify v-bind inline style value not updating

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, data-binding, vuetify.js

I have a tricky layout that I believe can only be responsive with JavaScript, but I can't manage to get inline styling with bound data to accomplish this. There is a wrapper element around an image that I want to be the height of the image plus `80px`. For brevity, I'll just post the two elements that I need working together, and cut out the extra markup because it is irrelevant.

```html
<v-flex v-resize="onResize" v-bind:style="{height: this.imageHeight}" xs12 md6>
  {{this.imageHeight}}
  <img src="../assets/images/image1.jpg" alt="image" ref="desktop-image">
</v-flex>
```

In data, I define `imageHeight` as `0` at first with the intention of having that value update once the page loads or the screen is resized.

```js
data () {
  return {
    imageHeight : 0
  }
}
```

Then in `mounted()`, I redefine the `imageHeight` data to be the height I want.

```js
this.imageHeight = this.$refs["desktop-image"].offsetHeight + 80;
```

I also include this in the resize method.

```
 onResize () {
    this.imageHeight = this.$refs["desktop-image"].offsetHeight + 80;
  }
```

Once the page loads or once I resize the screen, the outputted `{{this.imageHeight}}` value that I have above the image updates correctly, but it never updates in the `v-bind:style` on the image element so the height stays at `0px`.

How can I get the inline styling data to update like it does elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) CSS property must be either:

- a [`<length>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) value with length units (for non-zero values); e.g., `200px`

or:

- a [`<percentage>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/percentage) value; e.g., `100%`

A `number` value is invalid. The value is in the form of a string, so your code should append `'px'` to the calculated number:

```js
this.imageHeight = this.$refs["desktop-image"].offsetHeight + 80 + 'px';
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/GaaQWv)